# a case or the case

Tags: articles

What's the difference between "make a case"/ "make the case" and "be a case of"/ "be the case of"?

> 1 Jane made a case for change yesterday.
>
> 2 Jane made the case for change yesterday.
>
> 3 It's not a case of being nosy.
>
> 4 It's not the case of being nosy.

I don't see how "the case" can work. Can you give me a context in which it would work?

Answer (score 1):

It’s the difference between when there’s only one case versus when there are many, in some given context.

Your last example would definitely be “a case” - it’s a very generic thing to say and obviously there are an infinite number of “cases of being nosy”.

Your first example is a little trickier and requires more context. It could be either, depending on how many cases are being made, and whether we know about that. It might even also be correct to say:

> Jane made ***her*** case...